# How can i get the value of an Office UI Fabric SpinButton

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I need to get the value from Office UI Fabric SpinButton

I tried to get it with component Ref's but if i change a state the Spin Button is resetting to Default

```
 private SpinPerc: any = React.createRef();

<SpinButton
 defaultValue="0"
 componentRef={this.SpinPerc}
 min={0}
 max={100}
 step={1}
/>

COSTCENTER_IMPULSE_PERC: this.SpinPerc.current!.value,
```

Comment: please place your reduced testcase on codepen  and update your question pleaes with a link, easier to see what you have done https://aka.ms/fabricpen 

BAsically, a componentRef gives you the current state "value" if it gets reset, then your value of state is reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [PR](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/pull/7850) fixes the problem where SpinButton keeps resetting to default so you should now be able to get the value without any problem. Please let us know if it still persists.